# Laravel 4: custom select query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I use Laravel **DB::select** to return specific data from DB,

the problem is only one row return when use print_r($result)

```
    $questions = DB::select('
            select text
            from question 
            where id in (?) 
            order by field(id,?)',
            array($question_ids_list_str,$question_ids_list_str));


    print_r($questions);
```

how to return the rest of results?
thanks,

Comment: There is no `rest of results` apparently. This method returns array of stdObjects representing each row. Btw why do you use this instead of query builder, that's easier to use?

Comment: You should make sure what `$question_ids_list_str` contains. If it contains only one id or one existing id in database, select won't return more rows

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek $question_ids_list_str contains list of ids , tested

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk_deczo_ I use this way cause I work on DB with too many tables :(

Comment: @mwafi I have no idea what you mean by that. I wasn't talking about Eloquent, but query builder: `DB::table('question')->whereIn('id', $ids)->orderBy(DB::raw('field(id,'.implode(',',$ids).')'))->get();`

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this:

```
$ids = array(1, 2, 3); // Pass the ids in whereIn clause
$questions = DB::table('question')
               ->whereIn('id', $ids) 
               ->orderBy('id')
               ->get(array('text')); // Only get text field
```

Comment: this is working fine, but what is the wrong in DB::select, force it to retrieve only 1 row?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$questions = DB::select('
        select text
        from question 
        where id in (?) 
        order by field(id,?)',
        array($question_ids_list_str,$question_ids_list_str));
foreach($questions as $question) {
    echo $question;
}
```